# Since when is it commonplace to use conservation of energy for dynamics problems?

Tags: physics, thermodynamics, energy

If I throw an object, I can derive its trajectory using the forces acted on it. I can also do the same using conservation of energy.

**Since when is it commonplace to use conservation of energy for dynamics problems?**

Possibly related:

- The first law of thermodynamics, ie the realization that when you account for heat, energy is conserved, was not realized until the 19th century, if I remember well.
- The first derivation of energy conservation from a quantum mechanical point of view happened much later, probably around the middle of the 20th century.

Comment: Since before Newton. Wallis, Wren and Huygens described how to solve elastic collisions using conservation laws in 1668, see [The Laws of Impact](https://nature.berkeley.edu/departments/espm/env-hist/dissertation/ch_2.pdf). More broadly, mechanical conservation laws were used to solve equations of motion by Euler, Lagrange and others in the 18th century. Conservation of energy alone is not enough for a solution, but it is featured explicitly and prominently in [Hamiltonian dynamics (c.1833)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics).

Comment: Thank you! Very useful. Would you like to add this as an answer?